# The problem of checking the uniqueness of the value in the attribute constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a data retention system for unity. My plan is to mark fields to be saved with a special attribute, in the constructor of which I need to specify a key to save the data. The specified key must be unique.

I solved this problem in the following way: in the attribute constructor we check if the key is in the static list, if it is, we throw an error, if it is not, we add it and continue working.

But after compiling the scripts, I saw an error - the field I specified is not unique. This can't be because the attribute is applied only once in the whole project. I added a couple of outputs to the console to find out at what point the wrong behavior occurs. I found out that unity calls the attribute constructor 2 times.

I am at a complete loss as to how to solve this problem. I need to perform the check either at compile time or during scene editing.

I will also attach the code I wrote.

```cs
using FlexibleSaveSystem.Exceptions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace FlexibleSaveSystem
{
    public class SaveDataAttribute : PropertyAttribute
    {
        public readonly string Id;

        private static List<string> _engagedIds = new List<string>();
        public SaveDataAttribute(string id)
        {
            if (_engagedIds.Contains(id))
                throw new EngagedIdException(id);

            _engagedIds.Add(id);
            Id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```cs
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

namespace FlexibleSaveSystem
{
    public class Test : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SaveData("TestKey")]
        public string Value;

        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _valueHolder;

        private void Awake()
        {
            SaveSystem.OnReady += SaveSystem.Load;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            _valueHolder.text = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried asking AI. But I didn't get an adequate answer.

UPD:
After a couple of hours of rest, I open the project no error, the constructor was called 1 time everything is normal, but I should select the object on which the script hangs, the constructor is called again and everything breaks.

Comment: The constructor will be called everytime an instance of this script is created / loaded ... in unity serialization that can happen quite often.When you select it probably while being loaded into the Inspector. Why don't you rather use only a parameterless attribute and simply use the property path as serialization key? You could e.g. simply go by the path to the scene root + component type + field name